# kill tcp port binding by deleting proc/[0-9]/net/… in linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp, process, socket

I have a script to call syscall Kill the process that holds a certain TCP port in Linux (ubuntu). But even if I do that, sometimes the port still remains in `/proc/[0-9]/net` directory binding the port.

Is there any easy way to force to free the tcp port? I know which `proc/X` directory holds the port that I want to kill. Can I just delete the `/proc/XXX/` directory and consider the port is free to use after this deletion?

Some postings say I can use `fuser`, but I want to know what's going on in OS level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port remains bound because the calling application that is binding to the port does not use the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR`. You should fix the calling application to do this. In C:

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

This clears itself in the killed application after `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` seconds.
The best thing to do is fix your calling program to do the right thing though.